# Azure Service Bus Shared Access Signature Generation

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to generate Shared Access signature for the Azure service bus queue. Here is the code snippnet through which I am generating SAS token.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace SASTokenGeneration
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string resourceUri = "sb://xxxservicequeue.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxservicequeue;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx";
            string key = "token";
            string keyName = "xxxservicequeue";
            try
            {
                TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
                var expiry = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + week);
                string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
                HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
                var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this token in postman then sometime it gives

> MalformedToken: Failed to parse simple web token. azure sevice Bus

and Now I am getting

> 401 40103: Invalid authorization token signature

From error, I know that I am doing something wrong with connection string but cannot figure out what. Can you please point me in right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of sharing the screenshot of the code, please paste the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Problems may locate at

```
string resourceUri = "sb://xxxservicequeue.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxservicequeue;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx";
string key = "token";
string keyName = "xxxservicequeue";
```

The resourceUri is the full URI of the Service Bus resource to which access is claimed, in the format of `sb://xxxservicequeue.servicebus.windows.net/` or with specific entity you need to operate like `sb://xxxservicequeue.servicebus.windows.net/queueName`.

The key should be the value of `SharedAccessKeyKey` and keyName is SAS policy name like the default `RootManageSharedAccessKey`.

Have a look at [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#generate-a-shared-access-signature-token) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and really sorry for late reply. I was in a situation. I have read the doc and have done exactly as written. From code share above I can generate SAS token but when I use it on post man I am still getting 401 40103: error

Comment: @UsmanJaved If you have corrected the resourceUri and so on, can you confirm the SAS Policy you created is authorized to do what you tried in postman? e.g, With only `Listen` right, we can't send messages.

Comment: Yes I have checked that as well, all rights are given.

Comment: @UsmanJaved Could you elaborate which API you are trying to work with SAS? I will have a try as well to see whether I can provide a working sample.

Comment: You mean that I should send you resource uri and SAS token.

Comment: @UsmanJaved Nope, just tell me which [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/) you use. e.g, are you trying to send message or whatever?

Comment: Yes I am trying to send message

Comment: https://xxxservicequeue.servicebus.windows.net/xxxservicetopic/messages

Comment: @UsmanJaved Sorry for the delay. I follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-batch) and see Status:201 created in postman. Not very practical, but I suggest you create a new policy to try. If you only want to retrieve SAS for usage in SDK, you probably don't need to struggle with API test in postman, we could simply turn to [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#use-shared-access-signature-authorization) for help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have situation that I need to send and revieve message in jquery client thats why I need API.